# OSB Alerts Migration

Tags: weblogic, soa, osb

How can I configure alerts in Eclipse oepe? It's not easy to migrate all the alert rules and slas across environments.Is there any way to have all the alerts/SLAs migrated in case of change in environment like DEV to TEST without making any changes through sbconsole?

Whenever I exported the jar file(sbconfig.jar) from console and imported it in eclipse, all the alerts are not there in any service. The  becomes blank.

Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

Do you also export the Global Operation Settings from the OSBConfiguration? Because that info is not stored in a specific project.

[OSB Configurator](https://github.com/tomecode/OSB-Config-WLST-Configurator/wiki/OSB-Config-WLST-Configurator) definitely allows this, so it it is possible to put these settings into sbconfig.jar. In fact you can use this to add those settings to a pre-existing sbconfig.jar.

Note, however, that you might need to import it using `/sbconsole/` or WLST rather than from inside OEPE. OEPE has a bad habit of ignoring things it doesn't want to set.

Comment: My Problem is as under

Comment: First we need to create SLA rule via eclipse in normal way. So to do that
1> Export the jar from sbconsole and unzip it to copy the <aletRules> section from proxy/business service.
2> Inject the SLA rules copied to the respective service file just before </xml-fragment> section in eclipse. 3> Export  the sbconfig.jar from eclipse.
5> Now unzip the jar and remove the commented portion from the service.
6> Import the jar and activate changes.
7> Import the jar file via console using advanced options: unchecked option “Preserve Operational Values”

Comment: hi Trent-Can you show me an example in wlst that will guide me on how to configure sla alert rule in sbconfig.jar? As I told earlier, if I inject sla rules section in proxy service and create sbconfig.jar, that rule section becomes vanished. And it's pain to configure sla alerts in all the services across environments. I have checked your OSB configurator. Unfortunately hardly I found anything relevant to the SLA rule Migration talked about. Pls help.